# Get SharePoint DateTime in PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell

I would like to check the time passed from the last time a SharePoint file has been modified, but I cannot use the server time for the comparison, since it's different from the SharePoint one.

Is there a way to get the SharePoint current date in the Sharepoint Server PowerShell context?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it in this way

```
$web = Get-SPWeb $sourceSite
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility]::GetServerNow($web)
```